# Capital allowance and balancing charges on UK tax return

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom, sole-proprietorship, self-assessment

I'm trying to fill in the 'Capital allowance and balancing charges' page, thing is I'm pretty sure I don't have anything to charge in this yet the website won't accept £0.00 as a valid answer, can someone explain to me or give an example or something so I can move on with this?:
Here's what the page looks like:
[image: Capital allowance and balancing charges page]

P.S. apologies if this isn't the right place but I don't know where else to ask and I really need to get this done.

Comment: Have you tried leaving the fields blank instead of entering 0.00?

Comment: ...I misread the error message >_<, thank you @ganesh for pointing it out.

Comment: I just tested this with my tax return and leaving them blank works fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general when filling in the Self Assessment web form, you should leave fields blank if they would be 0.